# How to manage Kafka Topics when using Debezium with hundreds of databases each with hundreds of tables

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

Debezium uses one Kafka topic per table tracked by CDC. Apart from these, it also requires a couple of topics to track offset and schema history for each Database. With hundreds of databases each having hundreds of tables, is it still feasible to use Debezium to stream CDC events?

We can probably use SMT to route multiple tables into one topic but that is generally not advised. Are people using Debezium with these kind of setups?

Comment: Are you simple asking if Debezium can scale. That answer is yes, although the downstream applicability of what you really want to do here is unclear... For example, why would you need a single topic for all connectors? And baring any schema differences, how is that any different from having lots of regular Kafka producers?

Comment: No, I understand that Debezium is a widely used product and it can scale. My question is how do companies with a lot of databases and each db having a lot of tables set it up - as it would end up requiring many thousands Kafka topics. Possibly they also have accompanying huge Kafka clusters?

Comment: Large clusters are one solution. The largest cluster I worked with was several hundred TB of storage, but around 20+ brokers.